# How to read application log files from Azure Storage on Log Analytics

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I store application log in container in Azure Blob Storage. Image below:

[image]

I created a Workspace in Log Analytics, and configured log source pointing to Azure Blob Storage. Image below:

[image]

Despite, I configured the source, I don't know how to get data from these logs to read and show it in tables and graphics on Analytics.

The custom log files are stored by my application. They are result from logger of the app. My app is hosted by Azure AppService. I need a diagnostic about Application, not about storage status.

In this article https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/query-azure-storage-analytics-logs-in-azure-log-analytics/ shows how to read standalone files, I need to read Azure Files online.

How to get data from these log files and show it on tables and graphics on Azure Log Analytics?

Answer (score 2):

Data already persisted with in an external storage cannot be ingested into LA workspace.

Your example is using the data collector api, a public api which allows users to send data to LA data plan programmatically/using http, it's a generic solution with no specific affiliation to storage.

Option 1:
You can keep the data in place and build an external table on top of it by using Azure Data explorer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/externaltables

Option 2:
You can use Application insights to monitor your app, data can be exported into LA workspace.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource

Option 3:
Send app services diagnostic settings telemetry into LA workspace.
List of data types being covered:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-app-service-diagnostic-settings-feature-reaches-general-availability/

Option 4:
Extend your logger exporter to support data collector api, data collector api is quite simple and powerful, allowing you to create custom tables on the fly, change their schema with every new record and to utilize rest and http as a standard method to do so.

documentation and examples from various languages:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api

Answer (score -1):

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/manage-storage-analytics-logs?tabs=azure-portal) it says,

> The diagnostics logs are saved in a blob container named ***$logs*** in your storage account. You can view the log data using a storage explorer like the [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](https://storageexplorer.com/), or programmatically using the storage client library or PowerShell.

***Go to Containers and click on $logs or a name you have given***

[image]

***By clicking on $logs you will get the following output:***

[image]

***Make sure that Status is on in diagnostic settings and logging too.***

[image]

***References:***

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/manage-storage-analytics-logs?tabs=azure-portal
- [Analyse log files in Azure blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230697/analyse-log-files-in-azure-blob-storage)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging

Comment: Hi RithwikBojja-MT, I appreciate the answer, but the log files stored by my application is result from logger of the app. App is hosted by Azure AppService. It's not a diagnostic about storage status. I don't know if the case presented by you is the same that I'm facing.