# Azure Service Bus logging_enable=True

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

```
def send_single_message(sender):
    # create a Service Bus message
    message = ServiceBusMessage("Single Message")
    # send the message to the topic
    sender.send_messages(message)
    print("Sent a single message")
```

create a Service Bus client using the connection string

```
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)
with servicebus_client:
    # get a Topic Sender object to send messages to the topic
    sender = servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(topic_name=TOPIC_NAME)
    with sender:
        # send one message        
        send_single_message(sender)

print("Done sending messages")
print("-----------------------")
```

What does logging_enable=True mean here?

Comment: See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.servicebusclient?view=azure-python): Whether to output network trace logs to the logger. Default is False.

Comment: @PeterBons Thanks. Any idea, when it is set to True, where can I find the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Peter Bons, According [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.servicebusclient?view=azure-python) it says ,

> Whether to output network trace logs to the logger. Default is *False*.

***You can find the logs in ***`logs`*** in Monitoring section as below:***

[image]

***You need to try kql query to get the logs:***
***Example Kql Query:***

[image]

***References:***

- [How to read application log files from Azure Storage on Log Analytics - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72932355/how-to-read-application-log-files-from-azure-storage-on-log-analytics/72935256?noredirect=1#comment128826449_72935256)